# Talking notification of system events for Android

Tags: gratis, android, audio, notification

Whenever my Android phone wants to tell me anything, it beeps.

Always the same beep.

I imagine that I could configure it to use different sounds for different events, but is there an app where it will talk to me and tell me what just happened?

"You’ve got mail (TM)", "a new SMS", "wifi in range", "battery low", …

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://goo.gl/hCHwx0) ?

Comment: Yes, I have. All of those links whcih you so helpfully googled because I am apparently unable to read the text of system notifications (e.g "Voice Notify announces status bar notification messages", "Notification Reader does pretty much what the app name says it does. It reads out your notifications for you", etc, etc). Which is not what I asked for.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't all new Android phones come with [Talkback](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback&hl=en)?